# How to go through a list of items in a string

Tags: java

I need to count number of items in a String and show each of them separately liek 1) --- 2) ---- but the code does not work properly,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String forms = "[436,43,4,900,703,483,......]"; << a long list
       int counter = 0;
       int index =0;
       String temp = "";
       for(int i=0; i<=forms.length();i++)
       {
            index = forms.indexOf(",");
            temp = forms.substring(0, index+1);
            System.out.println(i + ") " + temp);
            forms = forms.replace(temp,"");
            counter++;
       }
       System.out.println("Counter" + counter);
    }
```

The result shows the code goes through the String but just to middle of it. it has around 700 items. but it shows there are only 350 items.

Comment: I saw there are some repeated items in the string, but you just want to print unique items, right?

Comment: I do not really know what the negative vote is for?

Comment: @HenryLeu, no I made mistake the numbers are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String forms = "[436,43,4,436,43,44]"; 
           forms=forms.replace("[", "");
           forms=forms.replace("]", "");
           String resultArray[]=forms.split(",");

           for(int i=0; i<resultArray.length;i++)
           {

               System.out.println(i + ") " + resultArray[i]);


           }
           System.out.println("Counter" + resultArray.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `replace` performs a replace-*all*, so if `temp` appears multiple times in `forms` (e.g. because of duplicate entries), then some entries will be deleted prematurely. (Actually it can be even worse than that: you can delete just *part* of an entry, if e.g. you have both `3,` and `123,`, and cause strange merging.)

The minimal fix is to dispense with `replace` and use `substring`:

```
forms = forms.substring(index+1);
```

but I recommend that you try `split` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Sting[] splitString = forms.split(",");`

This splits the string into multiple strings wherever there is a `,` : You can split using any other delimeter - i.e. : - by saying `forms.split(":");`

You can then refer to the individual (split) strings by saying `splitString[0]`... etc.

More specifically with regard to your case, you'll loop through the resulting string array as follows:

```
for (int curr = 0 ; curr < splitString.size(); curr++){
      System.out.println(i + ") " + splitString[curr]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String forms = "436,43,4,436,43,43"; 
       String[] parts = forms.split(",");
       int counter = parts.length;
       System.out.println("Counter" + counter);
}
```

Comment: Please care to explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split.To avoid ] and [ symbols we can use replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           String forms = "[436,43,4,436,43,43,......]"; 
           String[] splitString = forms.split(",");
             for(int i=1; i<=splitString.length;i++)
           {
                            System.out.println(i + ") " + splitString[i-1].replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));


           }
        }
```

Comment: @Daniel Morgan  did you checked this one